# Collapse selection to start of selection, not div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

How can I collapse selected text in a contentEditable div to the start *of the selection* , not the entire div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all major browsers except IE <= 8, you can use the [`collapseToStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/collapseToStart) method of the selection to collapse to the earliest point of the selection in document order, regardless of the direction of the selection:

```
window.getSelection().collapseToStart();
```

In IE <= 8, use the following, which is the equivalent of the first example above:

```
var sel = document.selection;
if (sel.type == "Text") {
    var range = sel.createRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.select();
}
```

Finally, putting these together to make a cross-browser function:

```
function collapseSelectionToStart() {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().collapseToStart();
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type == "Text") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yQS9G/2/

Comment: Perfect, you can disregard my email I sent you earlier :) Thanks a bunch Tim, exactly what I needed.